# Multiplying 2 value in database

Tags: sql, heidisql

I have a database.  I created it with HeidiSQL. Its look like this.

[image]

I enter the value-1 and value-2.

Is there a way to enter a formula to Result column  like " =Value-1 * Value-2 " ?  I want my database to calculate the Result when I enter my values to other cells.

Comment: You can use a trigger to update the column when a row is inserted.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? HeidiSQL is just a SQL client application that _connects_ to a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger is one way to achieve automated column content.

A second one is a view, which you can create additionally to the table. That view could contain SQL which generates the result:

```
SELECT value1, value2, value1*value2 AS result
```

A third (more modern) alternative is adding a virtual column in your existing table. You can do that with HeidiSQL's table editor, like shown in the screenshot. Just add a new column with INT data type, and set its Virtuality to "VIRTUAL", and Expression to "value-1 * value-2". That's it.

[image: creating a virtual column in HeidiSQL]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with HeidiSQL, but it appears to be a front end? What RDBMS are you using, for example SQL Server allows a computed column.

**SQL**

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD Result AS ([Value-1] * [Value-2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click your database name in the folder structure, go to --> create new then -->Trigger[image]

Then you can create a trigger that when entering data, will be activated on the entire column like this:

[image]

But you will need to know how to write the actual query and function. This requires basic knowledge that is generally generic and consistent of most all SQL languages.